# CreateFile как прочитать файл занятый другим процессом?

Tags: c++

как с помощью CreateFile прочитать документ даже если он занят другим процессом? какие флаги указать?

ставил разные варианты флагов, результата 0

Comment: файл даже нельзя скопировать контрл с контрл в, пишет что занят другим процессом

Comment: Если файл открыт в эксклюзивном режиме, то никак.